# change content div on layergroup change

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have two layers in a LayerGroup that I can toggle between and would like to update a control(bottom left in example) with the grades of the currently selected layer. How can I go about doing this in leaflet? This is what I currently have [here](http://gisinsight.com/sbcfb_leaflet/esri-leaflet-master/examples/doubleBase.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overlayadd` similar to the following:

```
map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
    if (eventLayer.name === 'Total') {
        // change content of div from one legend to the other
        // maybe something like this...
        this.removeControl(childrenLegend);
        totalLegend.addTo(this);
    } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Children') { 
        // change content of div back to other legend
        // maybe something like this...
        this.removeControl(childrenLegend);
        totalLegend.addTo(this);
    }
}
```